# How to sort child category collection

Tags: collection, category, magento-1

I a m using this function for getting child categories of current category

```
    public function getCurrentChildCategories()
    {
        $layer = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer');
        $category   = $layer->getCurrentCategory();

        $categories = $category->getChildrenCategories();
        $productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
        $layer->prepareProductCollection($productCollection);
        $productCollection->addCountToCategories($categories);
        return $categories;
    }
```

But i want to sort the collection using category name in ascending order i.e. alphabetically sort i have modified the function like this

```
    public function getCurrentChildCategories($sort_by = 'name', $sort_order = 'asc')
    {
        $layer = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer');
        $category   = $layer->getCurrentCategory();

        $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection();

        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addAttributeToSort('name','asc')
            ->addIdFilter($category->getChildren())
            ->joinUrlRewrite();
            ->load();

        $productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
        $layer->prepareProductCollection($productCollection);
        $productCollection->addCountToCategories($collection);
        return $collection;
    }
```

This should work but this is not working at all.. 
Any one having any idea about it.

Comment: after `joinUrlRewrite()` you have a semicolon. Also have you tried using `setOrder('name','asc');` instead of `addAttributeToSort`?

Comment: Did you find a solution? Please share the answer with us and mark it as solution!

Comment: Why are you using the `layer` model in the first place?

Answer (score 4):

If you remove the extra semi-colon from after joinUrlRewrite then this code will work.

But be aware by calling the function joinUrlRewrite you are limiting your function so it will only work when you are not using flat category catalogue as this function is missing from the class

```
Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Flat_Collection
```

It does however have the function addUrlRewriteToResult which would appear to give you the same results and when this is called on non flat categories it simply calls joinUrlRewrite so this would be the safer function to us.

**Normal Category Collection**

```
Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Collection
public function addUrlRewriteToResult()
{
    $this->joinUrlRewrite();
    return $this;
}
```

**Flat Category Collection**

```
Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Flat_Collection
public function addUrlRewriteToResult()
{
    $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
    $this->getSelect()->joinLeft(
        array('url_rewrite' => $this->getTable('core/url_rewrite')),
        'url_rewrite.category_id=main_table.entity_id AND url_rewrite.is_system=1 '.
        'AND url_rewrite.product_id IS NULL'.
        ' AND ' . $this->getConnection()->quoteInto('url_rewrite.store_id=?', $storeId).
        ' AND ' . $this->getConnection()->quoteInto('url_rewrite.id_path LIKE ?','category/%'),
        array('request_path')
    );
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: Nice! OP can just use `Mage_Catalog_Helper_Category_Flat::isEnabled()` to switch which method to call.

Comment: Yeah that would work. I added the full functions just for a bit more explanation.